# jQuery SlideShow Plugin source

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow

I am using this Plugin for my Slider

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/01/28/flipping-circle-slideshow/

Demo Link: http://tympanus.net/Development/CircleFlipSlideshow/

The Plugin is Beautify but it doesnt seem to have an Auto SlideShow feature built into it. I am trying to understand and modify the same so that i can get it to auto rotate after a few second. I havent created a jQuery plugin before so looking for some help into getting started with the same.

Source of the Plugin is here: http://pastebin.com/3vLfWAnc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information about how to make a jQuery plugin on jQuerys own homepage [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

I have also made a plugin tutorial that you can find [here](http://boxsheep.com/javascript-tutorials/jQuery-Plugin-tutorial_How-to-make-a-jQuery-plugin-part-1/)

Hope this helps, and good luck learning:)

EDIT:
This is a bit of a hack, but you could add a setInterval Method at line 207 like this:

```
  $navLeft.find( 'span' ).on( 'click.flipshow touchstart.flipshow', function() {
    self._navigate( $( this ), 'left' );
  } );
  setInterval(function() {
    self._navigate( $( this ), 'left' );
  },4000);
```

I haven't tested it, but it might work.

Comment: thanks a lot :D i am hoping its easy to add the modifications to the above plugin :D

Comment: I don't know how much you know about JavaScript and jQuery, but if you have a fair knowledge, I think you will find it quit easy. Of course modifying other peoples code can be harder than building your own from scratch.

Comment: The navigation arrows are added at line 198, and the navigation is controlled by the function at line 224.